# Обрезание текста в DIV

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли сделать так чтобы *`<DIV>`* не расширялся автоматически если текст не влезает в его размер, а обрезалась только видимая часть текста. И как это реализовать.
[image]

P.S. реализована функция изменения размера слоя, потом весь текст должен быть видимым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил сам, добавлением свойств в CSS

```
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
```